# How to make BusyBox running where my backend operating system can be xyz?

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, arch-linux, busybox

I am trying to setup BusyBox on top of ArchLinux, Fedora or Ubuntu. So that when i telnet i can get something like this following:

But how do i get started? Simply install Busybox on top of my existing distro? Will that wrap all my external third party libraries?

```
$ telnet 192.168.0.198 23
Trying 192.168.0.198...
Connected to 192.168.0.198.
Escape character is '^]'.

(none) login: root
Password: 


BusyBox v1.1.2 (2008.07.18-08:25+0000) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

Welcome to HiLinux.
-sh: nfsroot: not found
~ $ help

Built-in commands:
-------------------
        . : alias bg break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit
        export false fg getopts hash help jobs kill let local pwd read
        readonly return set shift times trap true type ulimit umask unalias
        unset wait
~ $ man alias
-sh: man: not found
```

**Follow up:**

For experiment i have tried on full-blown installed unit:

0) backend operating system is Arch, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS

1) install busy box on all

2) run busybox

```
$ busybox
BusyBox v1.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) multi-call binary.
Copyright (C) 1998-2009 Erik Andersen, Rob Landley, Denys Vlasenko
and others. Licensed under GPLv2.
See source distribution for full notice.

Usage: busybox [function] [arguments]...
   or: function [arguments]...

    BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
    utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
    link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
    will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
    [, [[, adjtimex, arping, ash, awk, basename, blockdev, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat,
    bzip2, cal, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, chvt, clear, cmp, cp, cpio, cut,
    date, dc, dd, deallocvt, df, dirname, dmesg, dnsdomainname, dos2unix, du,
    dumpkmap, dumpleases, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fgrep, find, fold, free,
    ftpget, ftpput, getopt, grep, gunzip, gzip, head, hexdump, hostid, hostname,
    httpd, id, ifconfig, ionice, ip, ipcalc, kill, killall, klogd, last, length,
    ln, loadfont, loadkmap, logger, logname, logread, losetup, ls, lzcat, lzma,
    md5sum, mdev, mkdir, mkfifo, mknod, mktemp, more, mount, mt, mv, nameif, nc,
    netstat, nslookup, od, openvt, patch, pidof, ping, ping6, printf, ps, pwd,
    rdate, readlink, realpath, renice, reset, rev, rm, rmdir, route, rpm, rpm2cpio,
    run-parts, sed, setkeycodes, sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha512sum, sleep, sort,
    start-stop-daemon, static-sh, strings, stty, swapoff, swapon, sync, sysctl,
    syslogd, tac, tail, tar, tee, telnet, test, tftp, time, top, touch, tr,
    traceroute, traceroute6, true, tty, udhcpc, udhcpd, umount, uname, uncompress,
    uniq, unix2dos, unlzma, unxz, unzip, uptime, usleep, uudecode, uuencode, vi,
    watch, watchdog, wc, wget, which, who, whoami, xargs, xz, xzcat, yes, zcat
```

Comment: You don't want BusyBox, you want to learn how to use `ssh`.  And *don't* `telnet` as root.

Comment: @geekosaur: BusyBox is cool fun thing, i am very curious to know how..

Comment: Telnet i have to use because my friend can code in PHP, CGI so that he can simply use the telnet commands to drive it i mean.

Comment: BusyBox is a mini-system for embedded platforms that don't have full installs.  On a system with a full install already, you would have to log in and then run it (you do *not* want to change root's shell to it; that would probably break your system completely).

Comment: @geekosaur: I know i know, but its all for fun crash and learn and fun.

Comment: `telnet` as root = your system is owned by everyone who can reach it.

Comment: Yes but that is sometime friendly in LAN network (not in WAN use).

Comment: Above edit, do not show exactly like other unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix utilities into a single executable."

BusyBox itself cannot be made to "run" as you ask in the title.  BusyBox is not a user interface like MythTV or XBMC.  Not sure what you mean by install "on top" of an already installed distribution, as the BusyBox executable file can be installed in the filesystem along with all the other utilities.   Only when you start replacing the standard utilities with symbolic links to the BusyBox version would you be clobbering the installation.

> So that when i telnet i can get something like this following:

If you want to use BusyBox's version of *telnet* instead of the distro's version of *telnet*, then you would have to edit the runlevel scripts (or *inetd* configuration) to use the BusyBox telnet daemon, *telnetd*, instead of the distro's *telnetd*.

For a quick experiment, check if any *telnet* or *inet* daemons are running in your system by listing all processes:

```
$ ps -A | grep net
```

If there is either a telnetd or inetd daemon, then you would have to stop the service or kill the daemon.  If there are no telnetd or inetd daemons, then you should be able to manually start the BusyBox telnetd daemon with (might have to preface with sudo):

```
$ busybox telnetd
```

Of course, after you have telnet'd into the PC, the shell would still probably invoke the distro's utilities according to PATH rather than the BusyBox versions.  You would have to either install the symbolic links or explicitly use

```
$ busybox [function] [arguments]...
```